# What does .ipa stand for?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, uti

What does the .ipa file extension (used for iOS app bundles) stand for? I'm guessing that it has something to do with iPhone app, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955970/what-does-ipa-file-stands-for

Comment: @Kudu Not useful since this question was asked here because it was off topic there. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your guess was correct.

`.ipa` stands for [**iOS App Store Package**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

Each `.ipa` file is compressed with a binary for the ARM architecture that can only be installed on iOS devices. If you change the extension to `.zip` you will be able to unzip it and view the contents.

Comment: Please check that link.

Comment: Link doesn’t mention "ios app store package”. Also “stands for” usually means an acronym. So one would expect it to be “IASP”. Other answers clarify that so no worries.

Answer (score 10):

According to Apple, `.ipa` stands for "iOS App Store Package". Wait a minute, that makes no sense at all. It originally stood for:

**iP**hone **A**rchive

Then, when iPhone OS became iOS, they made up this new translation for it to make its purpose more clear.

Comment: don't know why the down votes; a bit of history that should not be ignored.

Comment: @JerryAndrews Finally someone appreciates the etymology here! Thanks

Comment: What's your source for that claim?

Comment: Maybe they tried to sound cooler by making it sound like an alcohol

Answer (score 7):

IPA stands for "iOS App Store Package", according to Apple - read the iOS Developer Library - section "Tools Workflow Guide for iOS->Distributing Apps".

> [**Sending Your App to Testers**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html)
>
> To send your app to testers:
>
> 1. If you don’t have access to the project that generates the app, obtain an iOS App Store Package (IPA) file for your app from the appropriate teammate. Otherwise, generate the IPA file yourself:
>
>    a. Open the project in Xcode.
>
>    b. Archive your app.
>
>    c. Generate an IPA file for your app.
> 2. Download the user testing provisioning profile for your app from the iOS Provisioning Portal to your file system. (You don’t have to install this profile in Xcode.)
> 3. Email the user testing provisioning profile and the IPA file to your testers.

Answer (score 0):

.ipa stands for iOS Application Archive.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple... IPA means IPhone Application...

Comment: Might you have a reference for the phone portion of this acronym?

Answer (score -2):

As a rule, apps for the iPhone can only be obtained from the App Store as soon as they have been put up for sale there. The apps, so-called IPA files, can also be installed in a roundabout way.

There are various reasons why you might want to install an IPA file on your iPhone yourself. For example, to test a specially developed app or for other, less noble reasons. In this way, at least in theory, illegal copies of apps can be set up with the IPA files. However, you can also install IPA files in this way within narrow limits.

Answer (score -3):

It means Internet Protocol Address

Comment: Please read the question carefully. Context is important!

Comment: It means India Pale Ale. Upvote me, please.

Comment: Actually, it means I Poke Animals. Just FYI.